# How to make a failed payment in paypal sdk php

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to make a payment in sandbox that will fail .

I found on paypal docs that you can enter error code on amount and you will get a failed payment.but unfortunately its not working .

I wanted to test this to see how my app will behave if a payment fails

my app is redirecting if the payment is not success to main page with a session

```
if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
//MY DB LOGIC

}
else{

return redirect('/home')->with('error','Payment failed');
}
```

I'm using paypal-php-sdk with Laravel

Any idea if this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

So a few things to check for here:

- Did you enable negative testing in your sandbox account ([as described here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sandbox/sb-error-conditions/#enable-negative-testing))?
- Do you match the following criteria?

  > Negative testing can be used with Classic PayPal API versions 2.4 and later. And also note that negative testing is only available for business accounts.
- Do you specify the expected error code in the correct format?

  > To trigger an error condition on an amount-related field, specify a error code value as a number with two digits to the right of the decimal point. For example, specify a value of 107.55 to trigger the 10755 error.